# clone & live function with context parameter jquery 1.4

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have few div HTML elements and i am cloning it with a `clone(true)` option as i want to copy the events also.

Now the case there are certain click events in my HTML div blocks and while crating events i use context parameter also like

```
var $block ="<div class='task-create-content' >"+
                 "<div class='task-create-preview'>"+
                      "<div class='items'>" +
                           "<div><input type='text' class='edit wtp'/></div>" +
                           "<div><input type='text' class='edit wtp'/></div>" +
                      "</div>"+
                 "</div>");

$(".wtp", $block).live('click',function() {
     alert("hi");
})
```

Now , when i clone this block using `clone(true)`, click event doesn't get fire even if i am assigning context parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.live()` method needs the actual selector to match the element against.

Try this:

```
$(".task-create-content .wtp").live('click',function(){
     alert("hi");
});
```

It uses that selector at the root of the document to see what exactly received the click event. If there's a match, it fires the handler for that selector.

It seems as though you're assigning handlers directly for newly created elements. If you want to do that, use `.bind()`.

```
$(".wtp",$block).bind('click',function(){
     alert("hi");
});
```

...which is the same as doing:

```
$(".wtp",$block).click(function(){
     alert("hi");
});
```

---

**EDIT:**

<s>The correct</s> A couple of ways to confine a `live()` event to `$block` would be to pass `$block` as a third argument to `live()`.

```
$(".wtp").live('click',function(){
     alert("hi");
}, $block); // The handler is placed on $block and fired for .wtp elements within
```

...which is the same as using `.delegate()`

```
  // The handler is placed on $block and fired for .wtp elements within
$block.delegate('.wtp', 'click', function(){
     alert("hi");
});
```

jQuery's `.delegate()` just nicer packaging for passing the third argument to `.live()`. It just reorders the arguments, and calls `.live()`.

http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L875

Comment: I think it's not so much that the live() needs the actual selector instead of a context. According to the docs: "As of jQuery 1.4, live events can be bound to a DOM element "context" rather than to the default document root." http://api.jquery.com/live/

I would guess that the $block variable is not considered a DOM element context b/c it hasn't been appended anywhere in the document yet. You could add the element to the DOM, and then use a selector for it as part of your context, but then you're basically at patrick dw's solution anyway.

Comment: @joelt - Yes, `live()` events can be bound to a context (this is what makes `delegate()` work), but `live()` does rely on a proper selector. When you do `$(".wtp",$block).live(...`, jQuery flips it around to `$block.find(".wtp").live(...`, which means the event will be fired for all `.wtp` elements instead of just the ones contained in the `$block`. In order to apply a context to `.live()` as the docs suggest, you would need to pass `$block` as a third argument to `live()`. When there's no third argument present, `live()` uses the document root.

Comment: you can ectually use `$block` as the context for `live`, but in that case $block must be a single DOM element, you can achieve this using `$block = $("...");` -- I try and explain it in my answer.

Comment: Plus 100 to this.  This answer actually explained to me what delegate was supposed to accomplish. jQuery Docs do such a poor job of it.

Answer (score 2):

**First**, You have an extraneous closing parenthesis at the end of your `$block` declaration:

```
var $block = ...  "</div>");
```

This would stop the whole page from working.

---

**Second**, if you use a context as part of the `live()`, then the context has to be a single DOM elemnt.... it cannot be a string. To create a single DOM element, simply make use of jQuery ( `$block = $("...");`, so you should do:

```
var $block =$("<div class='task-create-content' >"+
                 "<div class='task-create-preview'>"+
                      "<div class='items'>" +
                           "<div><input type='text' class='edit wtp'/></div>" +
                           "<div><input type='text' class='edit wtp'/></div>" +
                      "</div>"+
                 "</div>");
```

Then when you refer to `$block` you will be referring to a DOM element. The context cannot simply be `$block`, since you want to bind the `click` function to a `$block` that is actually on the page in question, so you have to specify which `$block`/s. To do this use `$(".wtp", $block[0])`.

```
$(".wtp", $block[0]).live('click',function() {
     alert("hi");
})
```

I pick as the context the first `$block` in the DOM. You can substitute a variable for the index or do this some other way.

[**working jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/SzEvG/)

---

### **Working with clones**

Instead of using `live()`, I would use `bind()` to work with clones... like this:

Remember that `$block` must be a DOM element in this case too, so you have to define `$block` like:

```
$block = $(" ... ");
```

Then you can use and clone `$block` like this:

```
$(".wtp", $block).bind('click',function() {
     alert("hi");
})

$($block).clone(true).appendTo("body");

  // Let's change $block dynamically!
$("<div>Dynamic!</div>").appendTo($block);

$($block).clone(true).appendTo("body");
```

Make sure you include `true` when you clone so that you indicate that the event handlrs should be copied too.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/W4PEH/)

Comment: +1 - You're right. That surprises me a little. jQuery must track the original context which is then referenced by `.live()`.

Comment: Although, I do think that OP is ultimately trying to make `live()` work for his dynamically generated (cloned) elements. While a context could be applied by various means, it seems like he's ultimately trying to achieve `$(".task-create-content .wtp")`, since he's not adding `.wtp` elements to `.task-create-content` elements, but rather adding/cloning the entire `.task-create-content` with the `.wtp` inside.

Comment: @patrick - I think that's true. I also think using `bind()` in that case would be much simpler. I added this option, demonstrating that you can even change `$block` dynamically if you use `bind()`.